# Problema com a interação de um servidor http com arduino e axios js

Tags: javascript, web-service, http, arduino, axios

Estou criando um servidor http no arduino, que dado uma requisição ele responde o seguinte:

```
client.println("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
client.println("Content-Type: text/html");
client.println("Connection: close"); 
client.println("Refresh: 5");  

client.println();

client.println("<!DOCTYPE HTML>");

client.println("<html>");
timeNow = millis()/60000; 
String times = String(timeNow, DEC);

String response = "{\n\"Response\": {\"workTime\":\"";
  response += times;
  response += "\"},\n";

response += "\"status\": \"200\"\n}";

client.println(response);
client.println("<br />");

client.println("</html>");
```

no navegador obtenho isso:

[image: o que aparece na tela]

[image: Aba network]

headers do chrome:

```
Request URL: http://1**.**.**.202:***0/resetRelogio
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 200 OK
Remote Address: 1**.**.**.202:***0
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html
Refresh: 5
Accept: 
 text/html, 
 application/xhtml+xml, 
 application/xml;q=0.9,
 image/webp,
 image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,
 application/signed-exchange;v=b3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,pt-BR;q=0.8,pt;q=0.7
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Connection: keep-alive
Cookie: qrClose=true; JSESSIONID=4db49dbd10380e82eb364e4fcd9636
Host: 1**.**.**.202:***0
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Fedora; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 
(KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.75 Safari/537.36
```

[image: aba response]

No meu teste com axios tenho isso:

```
const axios = require('axios')


axios.get('http://172.40.24.202:4000/resetRelogio')

   .then(function (response) {
       console.log(response);
    })

    .catch(function (error) {

        console.log("error");
        console.log(error);
    })
```

como resposta temos:

[image: resposta console]

Já procurei muito no google, pelo que entendi o arduino fecha a conexão de forma inesperada, porém eu mando um

```
client.println("Connection: close");
```

que era para o browser entender a resposta e fechar a conexão.
precisava que o axios me retornasse os dados do body.

Comment: E existe um `/n` depois do `\"200\"` que está errado.

Comment: response += "\"status\": \"200\"/n}"; aqui faz parte do meu body de resposta, é um json o status code está no começo. 
me corrija se eu estiver errado

Comment: Mas este `/n` não deveria ser `\n`, que é uma quebra de linha?

Comment: sim, foi um erro de digitação. Obrigado!